# Eureka detect service status

Tags: java, node.js, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

**Context**

We are using Spring Cloud Netflix with Eureka as the service discovery and Zuul for proxying the services and load balance them.

The microservices are implemented using NodeJS and are registered at Eureka using the NPM module [eureka-js-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eureka-js-client) and a custom layer in between that handles the configuration and stuff that is generic for all microservices.

---

**Problem**

The problem is that Eureka does not recognize if one service goes down. This is a problem as we are having a development infrastructure with autodeployment that redeploys and restarts the microservices on different ports each time without restarting Eureka (and Zuul).

Therefore after a while we have ten or more instances of one microservice where only one is up but all are recognized as beeing `UP`.

---

**Solution Approach**

1. I tried setting the `heartbeatInterval` on the client lesser but that does not help.
2. I tried setting the `renewalThresholdUpdateIntervalMs` on the server lesser but that does not help either.
3. Many more frustrating, non-helping property tries…

---

**Question**

How do I configure Eureka to evict instances or to set status to `DOWN` of the instances that do not send a heartbeat in a reasonable time (not 30 minutes or so)?

---

**Code Snippets**

The server itself does not contain mentionable code (just a few annotations to start the Eureka server using Spring Cloud Starter).

The configuration of the Eureka server (I have removed all non-working tries):

```
server:
  port: 8761

spring:
  cloud:
    client:
      hostname: localhost

eureka:
  instance:
    address: 127.0.0.1
    hostname: ${spring.cloud.client.hostname}
```

The client configuration that is sent to the server (using [eureka-js-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eureka-js-client)):

```
{
    instance : {
        instanceId : `${CONFIG.instance.address}:${CONFIG.instance.name}:${CONFIG.instance.port}`,
        app : CONFIG.instance.name,
        hostName : CONFIG.instance.host,
        ipAddr : CONFIG.instance.address,
        port : {
            '$' : CONFIG.instance.port,
            '@enabled' : true
        },
        homePageUrl : `http://${CONFIG.instance.host}:${CONFIG.instance.port}/`,
        statusPageUrl : `http://${CONFIG.instance.host}:${CONFIG.instance.port}/info`,
        healthCheckUrl : `http://${CONFIG.instance.host}:${CONFIG.instance.port}/health`,
        vipAddress : CONFIG.instance.name,
        secureVipAddress : CONFIG.instance.name,
        dataCenterInfo : {
            '@class' : 'com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo',
            name : 'MyOwn'
        }
    },
    eureka : {
        host : CONFIG.eureka.host,
        port : CONFIG.eureka.port,
        servicePath : CONFIG.eureka.servicePath || '/eureka/apps/',
        healthCheckInterval : 5000
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> after a while we have ten or more instances of one microservice where
>   only one is up but all are recognized as beeing UP.

Eureka has a 'self preservation' mode. Where if less than 85% of instances heartbeats are registering, it will not evict any instances. You should be able to see a warning on the eureka dashboard.

Comment: Ok, when I turn the self-preservation mode, the services are evicted correctly. Is it possible to speed up the eviction? Currently it takes around 2-3 minutes to evict the services. Also: Is it possible to turn the warning that the self-preservation mode is disable off?

Comment: You can tweak the eviction time, can't tell you the property, on my phone. Can't disable the warning.

Comment: I now have changed `eureka.leaseInfo.renewalIntervalInSecs` to `10` and `eureka.leaseInfo.durationInSecs` to `20` and the heartbeat interval to 5 seconds. That speeds up the service eviction. - Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0):

When a graceful shutdown occurs after use, the clients trigger another REST call so that the server can wipe out all the data related to the caller.
If you will gracefully terminate Eureka client Eureka server will be updated immediatley.